# How to set a custom Dimension in GTM parallel to the UA tracking preset?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

i looking forward for a solution to set a custom dimension outside of the UA preset in the Google Tag Manager.

The Problem is that the Data for the dimension is not everywhere available. So i can not set dimension within the preset, i guess.

The usecase:
I have a zip code query in a layer to find out if the user is suppliable or not.
This information i will send to GA with a custom dimension.

Actually i listening for the div id of the two layer versions which are displayed after the query. Then i set the dimension like below but the UA Tag is then already fired on the page view:

```js
ga('set', 'dimension6', 'Yes');
```

Thanks for your reply! Hope my english is good enough. ;)

Comment: What do you mean by 'preset'? Are you referring to the UA tracking snippet? You can't use standard UA functions like your example. For one thing, you need to determine and utilise the tracker name within GTM. If you have a listener set up via a custom HTML tag, and please confirm this, then you can also push an event to the data layer at which point you can define the value for you custom dimension and fire that through an event tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by preset you mean the fields for custom dimensions in the GA tag template. You can use that without problems; if a GTM variable is not set it defaults to "undefined", and undefined values are ignored when you send them in custom dimensions.

Comment: I found out my problem is that the analytics tag get fired by pageview but the variables first are set when DOM is ready and the dataLayer is constructed. How is send it after this time?